# Python - Initializing List variable from List elements

Tags: python, list

Ex. Lets consider, I have a list,

`list_var = ['sales_qty' , 'returns_qty' , 'net_sales_qty' , 'sales_amt' , 'returns_amt' ,'product_discount_amt' , 'product_net_amt' ,'product_cost_amt' , 'gross_sales_amt' , 'supplier_disc_amt' , 'category_disc_amt' , 'topup_disc_amt' , 'value_at_cost']`

from this list element, i want to init these elements as `list` in the memory, so i could use `append, extend` method for these elements.

As follow,

```
#Need these variable in memory..
sales_qty = [], returns_qty  = [], net_sales_qty = [] ... value_at_cost = []

#list operation on variable..
sales_qty.append(5)
```

Is there any simple way to do that, so i could remove element or add element in list easily?

Comment: What exactly is `sales_qty` in `list_var = [sales_qty, ...]`? A reference to some object?

Comment: @NPE: this is string element in the list, for which i need to define as list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a dictionary of lists based on `list_var` .

```
list_var = ['sales_qty' , 'returns_qty' , 'net_sales_qty' , 'sales_amt' , 'returns_amt' ,'product_discount_amt' , 'product_net_amt' ,'product_cost_amt' , 'gross_sales_amt' , 'supplier_disc_amt' , 'category_disc_amt' , 'topup_disc_amt' , 'value_at_cost']

list_dic = {k: [] for k in list_var}
```

Now can access your lists through the `list_dic` dict:

```
list_dic['sales_qty'].append(123)
list_dic['category_disc_amt'].append('abc')
```

---

If you're using a python version that does not support dict comprehensions (python 2.6 or lower), you can use a list comprehension instead (as DSM explained in his comment):

```
list_dic = dict((k, []) for k in list_var)
```

Comment: {k: [] for k in list_var} this dict format not supported for python2.5 :(

Comment: @Niks: then you can use `dict((k, []) for k in list_var)` instead.  This is still the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) if you are invoking from global scope. Otherwise, use [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

```
list_var = ['sales_qty' , 'returns_qty' , 'net_sales_qty' , 'sales_amt' , 'returns_amt' ,'product_discount_amt' , 'product_net_amt' ,'product_cost_amt' , 'gross_sales_amt' , 'supplier_disc_amt' , 'category_disc_amt' , 'topup_disc_amt' , 'value_at_cost']

for item in list_var:
    vars()[item] = []

sales_qty.append(1)
sales_qty.append(3)
returns_qty.append(2)

print "Outside..."
print sales_qty
print returns_qty


def foo():
    global sales_qty

    sales_qty.append(4)

    print "Inside foo..."
    print sales_qty
    print returns_qty

    # This works if you want the whole thing inside a function
    print "Variable from inside foo..."
    globals()["new_var"] = []
    new_var.append(5)
    print new_var

foo()

print "Outside again..."
print sales_qty
print returns_qty
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Outside...
[1, 3]
[2]
Inside foo...
[1, 3, 4]
[2]
Variable from inside foo...
[5]
Outside again...
[1, 3, 4]
[2]
>>>
```

Comment: Are these init as local var or global var in the memory??

Comment: They will be local to the scope in which `vars()` is invoked.

Comment: Now try this from within a function.  As your link says: "Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored."  It only works by fluke in your test because you're working at module level.

Comment: Even if this would work, I don't see the point in creating variables dynamically. If you want to access them in your script, you need to know the name in advance, in which case you could just create them like any other ordinary variable: `sales_qty = []`

Comment: @ATOzTOA: the idea was to put the *whole* code inside a function and then run the function to see if it works. It will fail when it will try to access one of the newly created variables, e.g. sales_qty.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Then you can use `globals`. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, globals() will work -- and for that matter, using "exec" would work in local scope if you absolutely, positively, wanted to create local variables dynamically.  [Why, I've no idea.]   But now you not only have the problem that @DominicKexel pointed out, you're polluting the global scope.  That's deeply unpythonic.

Comment: @DSM I know, just answering the question... :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
list_var = [ 'abc', 'cde', 'fgh' ]

dict_var = dict()
for x in list_var:
    dict_var[x] = []

dict_var['abc'].append(5)
```

Comment: Take note that your `vars` variable hides the builtin function [vars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars). Nevertheless it can still be called as `__builtins__.vars`.